# Обязательно ли учить классы в php для создания сайта?

Tags: php

Я хотел создать пагинацию, но для создания сложной пагинации многие пишут классы. Поэтому вопрос: насколько важны классы в созданнии сайтов и что ими можно реализовать?

Comment: Теоретически, можно вообще не изучать классы и работать без них. Но, это получится как рубить дерево при помощи ножа.

Comment: Не обязательно если сайт небольшой и это, например, сайт визитка, лендинг. Если работаешь просто с конструкторами сайтов - тоже не надо, если нужно что-то прикрутить к уже существующим CMS - тоже не обязательно

Comment: @АлексейБелкин зависит от задач..... может быть человк всю жизнь будет делать сайты визитки....там не нужны никакие классы